# How does Binance trading platform calculate its VWAP value? Moving interval? From a fixed date in the past?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, binance

I'm perfecting my trading robot and I need to understand how the VWAP indicator is calculated by binance to match the VWAP that is showed on their trading platform.

For now, I just follow the calculation explained on the binance [article](https://academy.binance.com/economics/volume-weighted-average-price-vwap-explained#how-to-calculate-vwap) but it doesn't tell how many intervals are used for the calculus, or if that interval is even fixed, changing.

On the trading platform, in the VWAP settings, there is no sign of how many intervals they use. One can only see the output value and a few visual settings.

[image: What is showed on the graph]

[image: The settings of the VWAP]

Sometimes, by calculating the VWAP on a moving 26 intervals time frame seems to match-ish the VWAP's value showed on the exchange's platform, sometimes it's closer to 35 intervals.

Here's my code:

```py
def get_vwap(symbol=None, interval=None, start_str=None, klines=None, interval_number=5):
    if not klines:
        if ((not symbol) and (not interval) and (not start_str)):
            print("Missing at least klines OR symbol,interval,start_str")
            raise ValueError("Missing at least klines OR symbol,interval,start_str")
            
        else:
            klines= get_klines(symbol, interval, start_str)

    #Initialization
    temp_typical_price_times_volume = 0.0
    temp_volume = 0.0
    #VWAP = ∑ (Typical Price * Volume ) / ∑ Volume
    for i in range(len(klines)-interval_number,len(klines)):
        high_price = float(klines[i][2])
        low_price = float(klines[i][3])
        close_price = float(klines[i][4])

        #Typical price
        typical_price = (high_price + low_price + close_price) / 3
        
        volume = float(klines[i][5])

        temp_typical_price_times_volume += typical_price * volume

        temp_volume += volume

    #VWAP = ∑ (Typical Price * Volume ) / ∑ Volume
    vmap = temp_typical_price_times_volume / temp_volume
    return vmap
```

It could even be calculated from a fixed date, for that matter.

Matching Binance's VWAP is very important for me as Binance's VWAP is perfect for my trading style!

Comment: The typical ways of calculating VWAP are easy to research; it appears you've already implemented the basic one.  If what you see from Binance differs from anything you can program, then I suspect that Binance has a more complex model -- which would be their intellectual property.  In that case, how do you anticipate someone on Stack Overflow divulging the algorithm?

Comment: If you are trying to reverse-engineer the algorithm and have trouble with your modeling, then please upgrade your posting to reflect *that* approach.  Screen shots are generally not acceptable, especially blank ones.  Did you intend to post a graph?  We'll need a *lot* more information on your attempts and analysis to make this a good question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. This algorithm is pretty standard (that's a hello world in technical analysis). I anticipate people building trading bots that use Binance Exchange have figured out what intervale number is used and stack overflow seems the perfect place to ask those developers.

Comment: I have spent 0 time trying to figure out how they calculate their VWAP, so afraid I'm unable to give you an informed response on that front. But as to the best place to ask this question, my suggestion would be to use the [Binance API](https://t.me/binance_api_english) telegram.

Comment: Thank you somuch for the suggestion. I'll post the answer here for the comunity if I find the answer !

Comment: Nothing  on telegram. No one knows but I plotted multiple VWAP intervals and binance/TradeView VWAP is closer to 120. That's not perfect and the VWAP isn't that closed to closing prices than on binance, but that's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate your VWAPS on more data. Try increasing the amount of klines you download and recalculate your VWAP.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

The VWAP is calculated as the weighted average of prices over a specific period, and each price is weighted by the volume of assets traded at that price. The basic VWAP formula is as follows:

VWAP = (Σ (Price * Volume)) / Σ Volume

Where:

The price is the price of the transaction.
Volume is the amount of assets traded at that price.
Σ represents the total sum.